# Yii2 calling javascript function at another file

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I have a js file and a index file which are located in the same folder. This is my form. I have already register the script already too.

```
$this->registerJs($this->render('script.js'), \yii\web\VIEW::POS_READY);

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<div class="booth">
    <video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
    <a href="#" id="capture" class="button">Take Photo</a>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
       <?= Html::button('Save',['class'=>'btn btn-primary','onclick'=>'saveimage();']) ?>
</div>

 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

This is the function inside the js file.

```
function saveimage()
{
    var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

    console.log(123);

    })*/
}
```

When I clicked my button is show error `Uncaught Reference Error: saveimage is not defined`? Its there anyway to call the function?

I tried `'onclick'=> 'js:saveimage()'` too, but still not working.

Comment: Does the solution propose worked for you? If yes consider upvoting the answer, and if no tell us what other issues you are facing.

Comment: Also I would suggest you to go through the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->registerJs(
    "function saveimage()
     {
        var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content");

        console.log(123);

     }",
    \yii\web\VIEW::POS_READY,
    'my-button-handler'
);
```

Or alternatively, If you want to use a separate js file you can use below syntax:

```
$this->registerJsFile(
    '@web/js/script.js',
    ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]
);
```

> When working with the yii\web\View object you can dynamically register
>   frontend scripts. There are two dedicated methods for this:
>
> 1) registerJs() for inline scripts
>
> 2) registerJsFile() for external scripts

For more details refer to the [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#register-scripts).